# Package Optim.jl very slow

Tags: r, julia

I have built two programs almost identical in the languages **R** and **Julia**.

In advance I know there is a ways to improve the performance of the Julia code since I did not declare types and normally non-vectorized codes tend to be more efficient. However, both the Julia code and the **R** code are on the same terrain allow comparison.

**Note**: I started studying Julia for a week, so you can tell that I do not program very well with **Julia**.

I noticed that the Optim package provides the `optimize()` function. It's is very slow compared to the `optim()` function of the **R** language pertaining to the **stats** package that is installed by default along with the **R** language.

Below are the codes **R** and **Julia**, respectively:

**R code:**

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

Gexp <- function(par,x){
  lambda <- par[1]
  pexp(q = x, rate = lambda, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
}

gexp <- function(par,x){
  lambda <- par[1]
  dexp(x = x, rate = lambda, log = FALSE)
}

QGexp <- function(p,...){
  qexp(p,...)
}

Gweibull <- function(par,x){
  alpha <- par[1]
  beta <- par[2]
  pweibull(q = x, shape = alpha, scale = beta, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
}

QGweibull <- function(p,...){
  qweibull(p,...)
}

# Função de distribuição acumulada Exponentiated Kw-G class (EKw-G)
cdf_ekwg <- function(cdf,par,x,...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)

  (1 - (1 - cdf(par = npar, x = x)^a)^b)^c

}

# cdf_ekwg(cdf = G, par = c(0.2,0.4,0.21), x = 1, alpha = 1.1, beta = 1.2, lambda = 1)

# Função densidade de probabilidade Exponentiated Kw-G class (EKw-G)
pdf_ekwg <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){

  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  #cdf_ekwg_locale <- function(x){
  #  cdf_ekwg(cdf = cdf, par = par, x, ...)
  #}

  npar <- c(...)

  g = pdf(par = npar, x = x)
  G = cdf(par = npar, x = x)

  a * b * c * g * G^(a-1) * (1-G^a)^(b-1) * (1 - (1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)

  #numDeriv::grad(func = cdf_ekwg_locale, x = x, method = "simple")
}

#integrate(f = pdf_ekwg, par = c(1,1,1.5), lower = 0, upper = Inf, cdf = Gexp, pdf = gexp,
#           lambda = 1.5)

# Será fixado os parâmetros de G. Serão estimados os parâmetros a, b e c do
# modelo EKwG.

sample_ekwg <- function(QG, n, par, ...){

  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]

  u <- runif(n = n, min = 0, max = 1)
  p <- (1 - (1 - u^(1/c))^(1/b))^(1/a)

  QG(p = p, ...)

}

# Função de distribuição acumulada Exponentiated Kw-G class (EKw-G)
cdf_ekwg <- function(cdf,par,x,...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)

  (1 - (1 - cdf(par = npar, x = x)^a)^b)^c

}

# cdf_ekwg(cdf = G, par = c(0.2,0.4,0.21), x = 1, alpha = 1.1, beta = 1.2, lambda = 1)

# Função densidade de probabilidade Exponentiated Kw-G class (EKw-G)
pdf_ekwg <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){

  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  #cdf_ekwg_locale <- function(x){
  #  cdf_ekwg(cdf = cdf, par = par, x, ...)
  #}

  npar <- c(...)

  g = pdf(par = npar, x = x)
  G = cdf(par = npar, x = x)

  a * b * c * g * G^(a-1) * (1-G^a)^(b-1) * (1 - (1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)

  #numDeriv::grad(func = cdf_ekwg_locale, x = x, method = "simple")
}

# integrate(f = pdf_ekwg, par = c(1.4,1.3,0.5), lower = 0, upper = Inf, cdf = G,  alpha = 1.1, beta = 1.2)

loglikelihood <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){
  -sum(log(pdf_ekwg(cdf = cdf, pdf = pdf, par = par, x = x, ...)))
}

myoptim <- function(...) tryCatch(optim(...), error = function(e) NA)

G = Gexp
g = gexp
data = sample_ekwg(QG = QGexp, n = 550, par = c(1,1,1), rate = 1.5)
starts = c(1,1,1)

set.seed(0)
start = Sys.time()
for(i in 1:5){
  result <- myoptim(par = starts, fn = loglikelihood, x = data, cdf = G,
                    pdf = g, method = "Nelder-Mead",rate = 1.5)
}
Sys.time() - start
```

**Julia code**:

```
using Distributions
#using Cubature # Calculo de integrais numéricas.
#using Plots
using Optim
#using JuMP
#using NLopt

function gexp(x,par)
    λ = par[1]
    λ * exp(-λ * x)
end

# valor = hquadrature(x -> gexp(x,1), 0, 100)[1]

function Gexp(x,par)
    λ = par[1]
    1- exp(-λ * x)
end

function QGexp(x,par)
    λ = par[1]
    # A função Exponential no pacote Distributions é reparametrizada
    # como 1/lambda. Dessa forma, para trabalhar com densidade na forma
    # λ * exp(-λ*x) é preciso tomar 1/λ.
    quantile.(Exponential(1/λ),x)
end

function sample_ekwg(QG, n, par0, par1...)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]

    u = rand(n)

    p = (1 - (1 - u.^(1/c)).^(1/b)).^(1/a)

    QG(p, par1...)
end

# Função de distribuição acumulada Exponentiated Kw-G class (EKw-G)
function cdf_ekwg(cdf, x, par0, par1...)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]

    (1 - (1 - cdf.(x,par1...).^a).^b).^c
end

# Função densidade de probabilidade Exponentiated Kw-G class (EKw-G)
function pdf_ekwg(cdf, pdf, x, par0, par1...)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]

    g = pdf(x, par1...)
    G = cdf(x, par1...)

    a * b * c * g * G.^(a-1) * (1-G.^a).^(b-1) * (1 - (1-G.^a).^b).^(c-1)

end

# valor = hquadrature(x ->
# pdf_ekwg(Gexp,gexp, x, [1,1,1], 1), 0, 100)[1]

function loglike(cdf, pdf, x, par0, par1...)
  n = length(x)
  soma = 0
  for i = 1:n
      soma += log(pdf_ekwg(cdf, pdf, x[i], par0, par1...))
  end
  return -soma # Queremos minimizar loglike.
end

 G = Gexp
g = gexp
data = sample_ekwg(QGexp, 550, [1,1,1],1.5)
starts = [1,1,1]
par0 = [1,1,1]
par1 = [1.5]

srand(0) # set seed.

@time for i = 1:5
     optimize(par0 -> loglike(G, g, data, par0, par1), [1.3,1.2,2.1])
end
```

The configuration of the machine that executed both codes is below:

[image]

**Note**: The codes are not working with the same samples. However I believe that this will not be what will justify the great different in computational time.

In my hardware the **R** code cost **0.6508956** secs and the **Julia** code cost **27.180257** seconds.

Would anyone know how to get the code Julia to run faster than the R code? 
I would like a simple solution since it is promised great computational performances in Julia without much understanding of programming. See, in R it was not done anything too much to justify major fixes in the code Julia.

Best regards.

Comment: The R code is open source. Presumably (or should I presume) the Julia language has an interface to C?

Comment: Don't splat so much. That's really really bad for performance with arrays since the length of an array is not compile time information. Just pass the array around and you'll be fine.

Comment: It is not Optim.jl that is slow, but rather your functions. Your `loglike` is called around 8500 times and the optimization takes 16 seconds on my computer which is the same duration required to run `loglike` 8500 times.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to place the number of iterations considered in the optimization algorithm of **R**.

Comment: Use some of the macros from BenchmarkTools for more precision, instead of `@time`.

Comment: Heck, certainly the calls ta ke a lot of time. However, these same calls are made in R. No? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that R and Julia count number of iterations differently. This means that in the same number of iterations Julia performs **more function calls** but also **reaches a better approximation of the solution**. So the difference you report is not surprising.

Here is a minimal example showing this:

#### Julia

```
julia> using Optim

julia> function f(x)
           println(x)
           sum(x.^2)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> optimize(f, [10.0, 10.0, -10.0], Optim.Options(iterations = 10))
[10.0, 10.0, -10.0]
[15.025, 10.0, -10.0]
[10.0, 15.025, -10.0]
[10.0, 10.0, -14.975]
[13.35, 4.975, -13.3167]
[7.20833, 6.65, -15.5278]
[10.3722, 4.41667, -10.9213]
[10.4963, 2.55556, -9.57006]
[5.11975, 7.8287, -10.0819]
[2.37634, 8.77994, -9.00364]
[8.04009, 7.57366, -3.52135]
[8.31734, 7.88155, 0.480788]
[4.12665, 2.81136, -2.06194]
[2.16887, 0.41515, 0.584081]
[-1.92127, 8.82887, 4.27755]
[3.33362, 2.63711, 12.5652]
[2.57577, 7.50018, -4.51012]
[-6.43509, 3.28125, -0.246445]
[0.794297, -1.36448, -7.05921]
[-1.15731, 0.777307, -2.24052]
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Nelder-Mead
 * Starting Point: [10.0,10.0,-10.0]
 * Minimizer: [2.1688665345729614,0.4151501295534299, ...]
 * Minimum: 5.217482e+00
 * Iterations: 10
 * Convergence: false
   *  √(Σ(yᵢ-ȳ)²)/n < 1.0e-08: false
   * Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: true
 * Objective Calls: 20
```

#### R

```
> f <- function(x) {
+     print(x)
+     sum(x^2)
+ }
> 
> optim(c(10, 10, -10), f, control=list(maxit=10))
[1]  10  10 -10
[1]  11  10 -10
[1]  10  11 -10
[1] 10 10 -9
[1]  9.000000 10.666667 -9.333333
[1]  9.5 10.5 -9.5
[1]  9.333333  9.444444 -8.888889
[1]  9.000000  8.666667 -8.333333
[1]  8.666667  9.555556 -7.777778
[1]  9.000000  9.666667 -8.333333
[1]  9.444444  8.148148 -7.407407
[1]  9.666667  6.888889 -6.444444
$`par`
[1]  9.000000  8.666667 -8.333333

$value
[1] 225.5556

$counts
function gradient 
      12       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems that in the code I posted, I can make the Julia code more efficient than the R code, without having to spend some time since I can relax the convergence criterion of the algorithm by using the `` optimize`` function. I insist on not spending a bit of time improving the Julia code in this example since there was not much time spent on implementing the R code. The codes are very close. Thank you very much for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

In summery to the discussion above, there are several issues here:

1. splatting is slow as already was mentioned
2. the call of `optimize` was not wrapped in a function which also slowed down the computations
3. `loglike` was not type stable as you have defined `soma` as integer
4. both optimization routines could call `loglike` different number of times (due to their different configuration) - so it is better to benchmark a given number of calls to `loglike` - I have chosen 1000 below

Below I post a cleaned-up Julia code and R code that should do the same work and Julia is ~2x faster. The timings after precompilation in Julia are:

```
julia> experiment(Gexp, gexp, data, par0, par1)
  0.112414 seconds (2.75 M allocations: 41.992 MiB, 3.38% gc time)
```

and in R are

```
> start = Sys.time()
> for(i in 1:1000){
+   loglikelihood(G, g, starts, data, 1.5)
+ }
> Sys.time() - start
Time difference of 0.2812479 secs
```

Here are the cleaned-up codes (I hope I made no mistake when removing unnecessary parts :) - so please checked if I have not messed up somewhere).

#### Julia

```
using Distributions

gexp(x,λ) = λ * exp(-λ * x)
Gexp(x,λ) = 1.0 - exp(-λ * x)
QGexp(x,λ) = quantile.(Exponential(1/λ), x)

function sample_ekwg(QG, n, par0, par1)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]
    u = rand(n)
    p = (1 - (1 - u.^(1/c)).^(1/b)).^(1/a)
    QG(p, par1)
end

function pdf_ekwg(cdf, pdf, x, par0, par1)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]
    g = pdf(x, par1)
    G = cdf(x, par1)
    a*b*c*g*G^(a-1)*(1-G^a)^(b-1)*(1-(1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)
end

function loglike(cdf, pdf, x, par0, par1)
  soma = 0.0
  for v in x
      soma += log(pdf_ekwg(cdf, pdf, v, par0, par1))
  end
  return -soma
end

par0 = [1.0,1.0,1.0]
par1 = 1.5
data = sample_ekwg(QGexp, 550, par0,par1)

function experiment(G, g, data, par0, par1)
  @time for i = 1:1000
       loglike(G, g, data, par0, par1)
  end
end

experiment(Gexp, gexp, data, par0, par1)
```

#### R

```
Gexp <- function(par,x){
  lambda <- par[1]
  pexp(q = x, rate = lambda, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
}

gexp <- function(par,x){
  lambda <- par[1]
  dexp(x = x, rate = lambda, log = FALSE)
}

QGexp <- function(p,...){
  qexp(p,...)
}

cdf_ekwg <- function(cdf,par,x,...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)

  (1 - (1 - cdf(par = npar, x = x)^a)^b)^c

}

pdf_ekwg <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){

  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)
  g = pdf(par = npar, x = x)
  G = cdf(par = npar, x = x)
  a * b * c * g * G^(a-1) * (1-G^a)^(b-1) * (1 - (1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)
}

sample_ekwg <- function(QG, n, par, ...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  u <- runif(n = n, min = 0, max = 1)
  p <- (1 - (1 - u^(1/c))^(1/b))^(1/a)
  QG(p = p, ...)
}

cdf_ekwg <- function(cdf,par,x,...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)
  (1 - (1 - cdf(par = npar, x = x)^a)^b)^c

}

pdf_ekwg <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)
  g = pdf(par = npar, x = x)
  G = cdf(par = npar, x = x)
  a * b * c * g * G^(a-1) * (1-G^a)^(b-1) * (1 - (1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)
}

loglikelihood <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){
  -sum(log(pdf_ekwg(cdf = cdf, pdf = pdf, par = par, x = x, ...)))
}

G = Gexp
g = gexp
data = sample_ekwg(QG = QGexp, n = 550, par = c(1,1,1), rate = 1.5)
starts = c(1,1,1)

start = Sys.time()
for(i in 1:1000){
  loglikelihood(G, g, starts, data, 1.5)
}
Sys.time() - start
```

### EDIT - optimizing Julia code even more

I you would decide not to pass `Gexp` and `gexp` around but directly call them like:

```
function pdf_ekwg(x, par0, par1)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]
    g = gexp(x, par1)
    G = Gexp(x, par1)
    a*b*c*g*G^(a-1)*(1-G^a)^(b-1)*(1-(1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)
end
```

then the timing is yet 2x better:

```
julia> experiment(data, par0, par1)
  0.061860 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was missing to consider the ``optimize`` function.

Comment: I have the problem of making a bootstrap for bias correction of estimators. In each iteration I have to do an optimization of an objective function. I thought it would perform very well (even if it did not have the best programming practices in Julia) since the R code also does not consider best practices.

Comment: Of course to be fair, I will have to consider other function options for the ``optimize`` function . I will do this, but I suspect that at most I will have equivalence. I will try and return the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: As a side note, if you are interested in bootstrap, check https://github.com/juliangehring/Bootstrap.jl

Answer (score 0):

For a fair comparison between the `optim` functions of the R language and the `optimize` function **Optim** package of Julia, I considered the **Nelder-Mead** method with a maximum of **500** iterations and convergence tolerance in `1e^-8`. This is the standard R `optim` function.

**Julia**

```
using Distributions
using Optim

gexp(x,λ) = λ * exp(-λ * x)
Gexp(x,λ) = 1.0 - exp(-λ * x)
QGexp(x,λ) = quantile.(Exponential(1/λ), x)

function sample_ekwg(QG, n, par0, par1)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]
    u = rand(n)
    p = (1 - (1 - u.^(1/c)).^(1/b)).^(1/a)
    QG(p, par1)
end

function pdf_ekwg(cdf, pdf, x, par0, par1)
    a = par0[1]
    b = par0[2]
    c = par0[3]
    g = pdf(x, par1)
    G = cdf(x, par1)
    a*b*c*g*G^(a-1)*(1-G^a)^(b-1)*(1-(1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)
end

function loglike(cdf, pdf, x, par0, par1)
  soma = 0.0
  for v in x
      soma += log(pdf_ekwg(cdf, pdf, v, par0, par1))
  end
  return -soma
end

par0 = [1.0,1.0,1.0]
par1 = 1.5
n = 20
srand(0)
data = sample_ekwg(QGexp, 5000, par0,par1)

function experiment(G, g, data, par0, par1, n)
  result = Vector(length(par0)*n)
  @time for i = 1:n
       result[3i - 2 : 3i] = optimize(par0 -> loglike(G, g, data, par0, par1),
                                      par0, Optim.Options(iterations = 500, g_tol = 1e-8)).minimizer
       loglike(G, g, data, par0, par1)
  end
  return reshape(result,length(par0),n)'
end

experiment(Gexp, gexp, data, par0, par1, n)
```

**R**

```
Gexp <- function(par,x){
  lambda <- par[1]
  pexp(q = x, rate = lambda, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
}

gexp <- function(par,x){
  lambda <- par[1]
  dexp(x = x, rate = lambda, log = FALSE)
}

QGexp <- function(p,...){
  qexp(p,...)
}

cdf_ekwg <- function(cdf,par,x,...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)

  (1 - (1 - cdf(par = npar, x = x)^a)^b)^c

}

pdf_ekwg <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){

  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)
  g = pdf(par = npar, x = x)
  G = cdf(par = npar, x = x)
  a * b * c * g * G^(a-1) * (1-G^a)^(b-1) * (1 - (1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)
}

sample_ekwg <- function(QG, n, par, ...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  u <- runif(n = n, min = 0, max = 1)
  p <- (1 - (1 - u^(1/c))^(1/b))^(1/a)
  QG(p = p, ...)
}

cdf_ekwg <- function(cdf,par,x,...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)
  (1 - (1 - cdf(par = npar, x = x)^a)^b)^c

}

pdf_ekwg <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  c <- par[3]
  npar <- c(...)
  g = pdf(par = npar, x = x)
  G = cdf(par = npar, x = x)
  a * b * c * g * G^(a-1) * (1-G^a)^(b-1) * (1 - (1-G^a)^b)^(c-1)
}

loglikelihood <- function(cdf, pdf, par, x, ...){
  -sum(log(pdf_ekwg(cdf = cdf, pdf = pdf, par = par, x = x, ...)))
}

G = Gexp
g = gexp
set.seed(0)
data = sample_ekwg(QG = QGexp, n = 5e3, par = c(1,1,1), rate = 1.5)
starts = c(1,1,1)

start = Sys.time()
for(i in 1:20){
  result <- optim(par = starts, fn = loglikelihood, x = data, cdf = G,
                    pdf = g, method = "Nelder-Mead",rate = 1.5)
}
Sys.time() - start
```

I think the comparisons are now a bit more fair than the first comparison I made. The same programming practices I took in R were also considered in Julia. For example, in R, I did not have to think about optimizing the code, I just implemented it.

**Output Julia**

```
experiment(Gexp, gexp, data, par0, par1, n)
23.764565 seconds (289.59 M allocations: 4.316 GiB, 2.09% gc time)
```

**Output R**

```
start = Sys.time()
for(i in 1:20){
  result <- optim(par = starts, fn = loglikelihood, x = data, cdf = G,
                    pdf = g, method = "Nelder-Mead",rate = 1.5)
}
Sys.time() - start
Time difference of 12.50351 secs
```

Comment: Thanks. I have investigated into it under several settings and it seems that Optim.jl performs ~2x more calls to optimized function than optimization in R (I have calculated number of calls).

Comment: You can't just show the timings though, you have to show that they both convergence to a local minimum or at least achieved an objective value that is comparable.

I'm sorry, but I don't know any R (I don't even have it installed), but the 2x number of function evaluations worries me a bit. It could be that we're hitting different branches because we're using different parameters, but I get slightly worries that we are making a function evaluation we should be making.